# SWIG cannot handle 64-bit c-pointer correctly

Tags: c, tcl, swig, 32bit-64bit

I have some C-APIs which will be called by tcl scripts. I use SWIG to wrap the C-APIs. But the tcl process gets crash when I run the script on 64-bit platform. Looks like the c-pointer is not handled correctly by SWIG. See details below.

Here is my C-API, it's very simple.

```
MsgHeader_t *
headerGet(void)
{
    printf("***********     headerGet in capis_swig.c: %p\n", &currHeader);
    return &currHeader;
}
```

Here is the related codes in the capis_wrap.c(generated by SWIG):

```
SWIGINTERN int
_wrap_headerGet(ClientData clientData SWIGUNUSED, Tcl_Interp *interp, 
int objc, Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[]) {
  MsgHeader_t *result = 0 ;

  if (SWIG_GetArgs(interp, objc, objv,":headerGet ") == TCL_ERROR) SWIG_fail;
  printf("***********     begin to call C-API headerGet\n");
  result = (MsgHeader_t *)headerGet();
  printf("***********     headerGet in capis_wrap.c: %p\n", result);
  Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, 
      SWIG_NewInstanceObj( SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_MsgHeader_t ,0));
  return TCL_OK;
fail:
  return TCL_ERROR;
}
```

And here is the output in console:

```
*********** Line 268: 0 : msgHeader 
***********     begin to call C-API headerGet
***********     headerGet in capis_swig.c: 0x7f8bfc507290
***********     headerGet in capis_wrap.c: 0xfffffffffc507290
...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

According to http://www.swig.org/Release/RELEASENOTES, SWIG-1.3.22 has the feature "64 bit TCL support". I have tried the version 1.3.38 (32-bit) and 3.0.10 (64-bit), but got the same crash for both versions. Did I miss something to enable the 64-bit support?

BTW, my tcl is 8.5.19 (64-bit), and the codes run well on 32-bit platform.

Looks like the issue is that the 64-bit c-pointer cannot be handled by SWIG correctly.  I am unfamiliar with swig. I appreciate very much if anyone can help.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: It looks like `headerGet()` is not declared in your capis_wrap.c. This is illegal and won't work. You need to instruct SWIG to include an appropriate header file with a declaration of `headerGet()`. You should also never ever use casts in order to "fix" a compilation error.

Comment: *Sorry I cannot post "minimal, complete, and verifiable example"* This is a hard requirement. You need to come up with a way for others to reproduce your problem. If the project you are working on is too large, create a completely separate small project and reproduce your problem there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I cannot post "minimal, complete, and verifiable example". The code snippets are from a large project. It's hard to split them.

Actually headerGet() is declared in capis_swig.h and it's a input when generates capis_wrap.c, in Makefile, I have this:

capis_wrap.c: capis_swig.h
 swig -includeall -ignoremissing -warn=0 -w201,302,305 -tcl8 -o capis_wrap.c

Comment: There is no possibility to make progress without being able to reproduce your problem. Find a way.

Comment: Ok, let me try and update you.

Comment: @jeff.lu: although I agree strongly with n.m. about the need for an [mcve], I also  think the most likely cause is that the declaration of `getHeader` is not visible when the swig-generated wrapper is compiled. Make sure that you compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall`.) Don't just assume that swig will add an include for the needed header file. Check to see if it did.

Comment: In my experiments SWIG does **not** generate a cast in `result = headerGet()`. If yours does, it's weird. Why would it? If you had to insert the cast, manually, there is a clear problem. I have swig 1.3.36.

Comment: result = headerGet() is generated by SWIG. In the code snippet above, only the printf lines are added by me.

Comment: I take it back, it does generate a cast. Weird...

Comment: I am certain your source doesn't include a declaration. There's no other way for this output to be produced. Remove the cast and compile the wrapper with the highest warning level possible.

Comment: @n.m. I got this warnings when compiling with -wall
  capis_wrap.c: In function _wrap_headerGet:
  capis_wrap.c:42720: warning: implicit declaration of function headerGet  
  capis_wrap.c:42720: warning: nested extern declaration of headerGet
  capis_wrap.c:42720: warning: cast from function call of type int to non-matching type struct MsgHeader_t *
  capis_wrap.c:42720: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated source doesn't see a declaration of `headerGet`.

Make sure you have a header file where `headerGet()` is correctly declared, and put an include directive inside the .i file:

```
%module headerGet
%{
#include "headerGet.h"
%}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine after add the #include. Thanks again.